# MTree addon showing blank nodes

Tags: add-on, modular-tree-addon

Anybody knows why the nodes on the MTree add-on are showing blank?

A few days ago I started working on a tree, all going good, I was chuffed with it, I saved and closed the file.

Today I open the file and the nodes are 'empty'. I've tried removing and reinstalling the add-on but outcome is the same. Same thing if I want to start a new tree from scratch in a new empty file.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's a third-party addon, not an internal Blender one. It looks as if it's being actively discussed [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/modular-tree/674043/1044) so it's probably best to ask there.

Comment: Thanks John! I have posted the question there as well.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with this problem, it appears to be an issue with Blender Python API side, and there's a fix. Link found in this [discussion](https://github.com/MaximeHerpin/modular_tree/issues/277)